# Are there any alternative words that can be used to refer to a particular thing?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I usually write new words I learned or found on a website to help me remember them better. For example, I learned the word "holster" and I wrote "A holster is a thing used to cover a gun."

This is perfectly fine to me if there are 2 or 3 words per day. But the problem is I learn about 10 - 15 new words a day and it looks strange to use the word "thing" over and over again.

I want to know alternative words for the word "thing."

**Update**

After I read several answers to this question. It sounds like I can say "A holster is used to cover a gun." If so, is this sentence sounds better than "A holster is a thing used to cover a gun"?

Comment: I think you should just say: > It looks strange to see the same word over and over again. That way they do not have to fill in what *thing* you are talking about, but are clear that you mean a *word*.

Comment: But you could avoid it altogether by writing  *A holster is what is used to cover a gun* or even simpler, *A holster is used to cover a gun.*   I probably would have written '*A holster straps to a person's body and is used to carry a gun*' though.

Comment: I'd change that definition to "A holster is a cloth or leather case used to carry a gun." See the dictionary entry for [holster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holster).

Comment: I'd add "on your person" as a key element of that definition, or "a holster is a cloth or leather case that gets strapped onto your body in order to carry a gun."

Comment: @Hellion- That's the first usage I thought of too, but BillFranke is right, there is such a thing as a [saddle holster](http://www.russfawson.com/photos/accessories/PommelBag_03.jpg)

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, not all words refer to *things*, in the usual sense of tangible objects. It's therefore not always possible to refer to *anything* as a *thing*.

Moreover, the word almost always carries more meaning than simply an idea as a nondescript thing. Consider your own example for instance.

> [**hol·ster**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/holster)  /ˈhōlstər/ *noun* [ODO]
>   A holder for carrying a handgun or other firearm, typically made of leather and worn on a belt or under the arm.
>   *verb*
>   Put (a gun) into its holster.

Notice the use of the descriptor ***holder***, which is very significant and useful here. Calling it merely a thing would have led to loss of this information.

When you learn a new word that is a verb, adjective, adverb, or another POS, it may not be possible to use *thing*, as we already said above. We have to say, for example in the above case, ***the act of*** (putting a gun into its holder).

Through a careful choice on a case to case basis, you can record more useful information about the word.

Comment: @code4eight  Note, too, that following Kris' recommendation provides you an opportunity to practice *more* words, so you get twice the return on your effort.

Comment: What does "POS" in the second paragraph from the bottom mean?

Comment: @code4eight POS here stands for *Part of Speech*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *object* in place of *thing*, as in "A holster is an object used to cover a gun."

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question will put many more items on your list.

'Thing' is the most general physical object and any synonym might work in general (**object**, **entity**, etc). But it is also more specific than 'noun'.

If the word you have is a kind of thing, then you can always use a term that is more specific between 'thing' and more general than your new word. For example, among many things, a holster is: **an accessory**, **a piece of equipment**, **a receptacle**, **a firearm holder**, etc etc. For example, 'a holster is a **holder** for firearms that usually is worn hanging from a belt'). Another example is to follow the 'is a' relationship:

> A dog is a canine is a carnivore is a mammal is an animal is an organism ...

But maybe your new word is not a thing. It could be a **concept**, like 'honesty' ("honesty is an **abstract principle** that favors answering with the truth") or a feeling like 'nausea' ("nausea is a **symptom** of intestinal distress that feels like you're about to vomit.").

At some point, there may not be enough single-word nouns to cover the entire range from general to specific, and then modifiers will be added:

> Invisibility is a property, a property of substances, a visual property of substances, ...

This also goes for verbs or adjectives or whatever: "to run is **to move** you legs quickly", "pink is a color between white and red".

This successive refinement is what eventually ends in a complete definition of your word whatever it is.

What comes out of this is that you can make it more specific, but then you have more words to learn.